# Passing numbers beetwen first and third activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi im working on calculator and i have problem. Namely when i want to pass numbers from edit text from first activity in third activity i cant do anything with it. For example to first number i wanna add 3 and set show new value after add i cant. I know I got a bit confused but I hope you will know what's going on

Here is 1st activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this., Main2Activity.class);
            String age= et1.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("AGE", age);

            String weight= et2.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("WEIGHT", weight);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
        }
    };


}
```

}

2nd:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
     btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
             String age= getIntent().getStringExtra("AGE");
             intent.putExtra("AGE", age);

             String weight= getIntent().getStringExtra("WEIGHT");
             intent.putExtra("WEIGHT", weight);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
}
```

}

3rd:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String weight= getIntent().getStringExtra("WEIGHT");
    String age= getIntent().getStringExtra("AGE");




    double x= age*21;
    tv1.setText(x);
}
```

}

Comment: I think its cleaner to just use a db, rather than directly trying to pass values...

Comment: You are only using Main2Activity and MainActivity seems like 3rd activity didn't participate.

Comment: I believe you haven't passed any value to `MainActivity3`. from `MainActivity2` you're again passing to `MainActivity`

Comment: I corrected the error in second activitie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in the code, first, make sure you are really on the third activity. Because there are only two activities which I can see in the code: MainActivity, Main2Activity.

Another thing is in the 3rd activity's onCreate, you are giving `double` value to the `setText` method and It will throw ResourceNotFound Exception because there is no method, which name is `setText` and accept `double` type of parameter. To make this work you need to convert `double` value to `String`, like this:

```
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

**Update**

Also, your age variable is of String type, so to build a correct mathematical expression you need to convert the type of age variable to Integer:
  So :

`double x= Integer.parseInt(age)*21;`

Comment: I meant this fragment more because I can't do anything about it because I get the error message "error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
        double x = age * 21;
                     ^
  first type: String